# #c async MySqlConnector

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

maybe someone can help me to make my mysql queries asynchronous.

Unfortunately my knowledge is not that far, so I hope for your help

In the examples in the code I show my current MySQL connection that works without any problems

Unfortunately it is the case when larger amounts of data are requested
That caused lag.

```
         public static DataTable ExecuteQueryWithResult(string sql, bool isRecconect = false)
                {
                    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(_connStr))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            DataTable results = new DataTable();
                            results.Load(rdr);
                            rdr.Close();
                            MySqlConnection.ClearAllPoolsAsync();
                            conn.CloseAsync();
                            return results;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("DATABASE: [CONNECT] " + (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open));
                            Debug.WriteLine("DATABASE: [ERROR] " + ex);
                            Debug.WriteLine("DATABASE: [ERROR SQL] " + sql);
                        }
                    }
        
                    if (isRecconect)
                        return new DataTable();
        
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    return ExecuteQueryWithResult(sql, true);
                }



 public static void LoadAll()
            {
                DataTable tbl = LoadData.MySql.ExecuteQueryWithResult("SELECT * FROM apartment");
        
                foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
                {
                    Sync.Data.Set(-1005000 + (int) row["id"], "id", (int) row["id"]);
                    Sync.Data.Set(-1005000 + (int) row["id"], "user_id", (int) row["user_id"]);
                    Sync.Data.Set(-1005000 + (int) row["id"], "user_name", (string) row["user_name"]);
                    Sync.Data.Set(-1005000 + (int) row["id"], "price", (int) row["price"]);
                    Sync.Data.Set(-1005000 + (int) row["id"], "build_id", (int) row["build_id"]);
                    Sync.Data.Set(-1005000 + (int) row["id"], "floor", (int) row["floor"]);
                    Sync.Data.Set(-1005000 + (int) row["id"], "interior_id", (int) row["interior_id"]);
                    Sync.Data.Set(-1005000 + (int) row["id"], "is_exterior", (bool) row["is_exterior"]);
                    Sync.Data.Set(-1005000 + (int) row["id"], "pin", (int) row["pin"]);
        
                    Count++;
                }
                
                Debug.WriteLine("Apartment load: " + Count);
            }
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You can use dapper (https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) to simplify data extraction. It provides extensions to IDbConnection (MySqlConnection implements it) which much simple than if you work with clear MySqlConnection. You need QueryAsync<T> method for your purposes.

Comment: If you're using MySql.Data, be aware that it's a longstanding bug that it doesn't implement _any_ async operations: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111. You need to switch to https://mysqlconnector.net/ (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) to get async MySQL DB operations.